# i am not able to generate ID for user

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I want to generate id. My application works in 3-tier (using asp.net & vs 2008). so to do this i'm calling a method from user interface(webpg1.aspx.cs) written in class1.cs file. I have assumed that there is no record in database at present, so that id could be as 1,2,3...n. So please make me where I am going wrong.
`Call` from `webpg1.aspx.cs`

```
int verify = j.insertReg(ad,un,pwd);
```

implementation `class1.cs`

```
public int regUser(int id, string un, string pwd)
{
  int cms = 0; 
  int id1 = 0;
  int c2 = openDb();

  if (c2 < 0)
  {
    if (ad ==0)
      id1 = callgenId(ad);

   cm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO regAgnt VALUES('"
                                + id1 +"','"+ un +"','"+ pwd +"')",cn);
    cms = cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  else
  {
    cms = c2;
  }

  return cms;
}

private int callgenId(int id)
{
  int idi = 0;
  cm = new SqlCommand("select MAX(aid) from regAgnt", cn);
  dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
  while (dr.Read())
  {
    if(Convert.ToInt32(dr[0])== 0)
      idi += 1;

    dr.Close();
   }
   return idi;
}
```

it produces output of 0 in the table, I have also bind the default value as 0 in the table.

Thanks!

Comment: If there is no info in your result set - dr.Read() doesn't happen.

Comment: Why don't you just have an autoincrement field in the table instead of rolling your own?

Comment: if there is no info found in result set than what should i do to make data set in DataReader object..?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no info in your result set - dr.Read() doesn't happen.

Comment: after forcing it to check whether dr is returning null or not-  `dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
                idi = dr.IsDBNull(1) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);` I m getting this error - `Invalid attempt to read when no data present.` In this situation what could be solution.

Comment: is it mean.. it is not reaching in database.table or not able to fetch any record from table.?

Comment: if my sql query to select highest id correct? ... i could not get what is going wrong.. same query is running absolutely on desktop app platform.

Comment: If there are no records in the table, it will never execute the read, and your id will always be zero.  It would be much easier to use an autoincrement on your primary key in your db and you don't have to use your custom logic.

Comment: actually sir, my table has record in it, and about - autoincreament, if user reload the button with same records it will create same user with new id, as id is generating without letting know to the user.

Comment: oh i see, but i think it can be improved once we would be able to get incremented with the help of custom code. would you please suggest me some Hint to find the way to read data from the table.. thanks